# Database structure advice needed about services provided by user

Tags: algorithm, database-schema

My project calls for something similar to yellow pages:
Storing users services and providing look-up by service.

My current solution is very rigid and cumbersome -
I have 3 preset lists: Industry, Trade, Specialty.
User starts at top level and defines his service(s).
I also create a "search in place" option where providing strings performs a look-up in the string of "Industry - Trade - Specialty".

I noticed Google, LinkedIn and yellow-pages provide a much easier solution where users can put in free text, and the system will give results for Certified Public Accountant even if search term is CPA.

Any thoughts on a smarter, more efficient and easy for the user solution?
I am not looking for the exact db structure, the general algorithm will suffice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a tag structure? That allows entries in multiple places, tag hierarchies, tag "remaps" (standardize tag names).

Basically, you do NOT have a hierarchy in - entries are flat, but have tags attached that can form hierarchies. This is flexibility you need - a company may provide multiple services, you may want to have tags standardized, too.

Simply said:

- A table (or more - I keep it general) for the entries
- A table for tags, parenting itself (form a tree)
- An EntryTAble tag.

The tag table must allow crosslinks (alternative tag, status etc.).

Comment: I think I get you idea, but I'm missing something - first table:id,entry | second table: id,tag,child-of | Third table: first_table.id,second_table.id - I guess I create the second table to control hierarchy, and allow users to add entry to first table but my problem is what logic is used to connect first and second table into the third table? Should I do this manually?
Thank you very much for your ideas and followup.

Comment: WHat else? I mean, this requires intelligence, at least a trace. I do not mean this insulting, but unless you found a magic way to get from something like a company name / address to the businesses it does, this IS a manual process. It can be scripted (I now import 4000 of service A), but it is a user who has to decide where to hook up the entries, logically.